# Spring Data Redis as cache manager of a Spring MVC, spring security fails authentication

Tags: caching, spring-security, redis, spring-data-jpa, jedis

I am working on utilising cache with spring mvc(Spring framework 5.1.0) application that uses spring security(5.1.4) with Spring data JPA(2.0.13). I have tested the caching with SimpleCaching that is available in Spring and works fine. I want to move to a better caching manager such as Redis (Redis server 5.0.3). I have configured the RedisCacheManager as such (Spring data redis:2.0.13; Jedis: 2.10.2):

```
<bean id="poolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxIdle" value="8"/>
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="6000"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:host-name="localhost" p:port="6379" 
      p:pool-config-ref="poolConfig" p:usePool="true"/>

<bean id="redisCacheWriter" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter">
    <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultRedisCacheConfiguration" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration"
      factory-method="defaultCacheConfig"/>


    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"  
   c:cacheWriter-ref="redisCacheWriter" c:defaultCacheConfiguration-ref="defaultRedisCacheConfiguration" c:initialCacheNames="user"
   p:transaction-aware="true"/>
```

I use @Cachable and @CachePut to perform the caching. I see in the log that it correctly picks up the cache and initilise it from the retrieved value from the database.

`TRACE [ework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor]: Computed cache key 'User= \********\' for operation Builder[public abstract eee.entity.User eee.repository.UserRepository.findByEmail(java.lang.String)] caches=[user] | key=''User= ' + #result.email' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='#result != null' | unless=''`

However, when a user attempts to login it fails indicating that the user doesn't exist. As if the data doesn't exist in the database. This only happens if I switch to Redis as cacheManager. Any ideas? Thanks in advance